# Маршрутизация Windows 2008/OpenVPN

Tags: роутинг, маршрутизация, windows-server-2008, openvpn

Имеется VPN-туннель между двумя сетями, построенный по статье http://yvision.kz/post/395551
OpenVPN сервер работает на Windows 2008. Соединение точка-точка работает, но второй компьютер за win2008 не видно. В статье для включения маршрутизации советуют

> Запускаем редактор реестра regedit.exe на сервере где установлен OpenVPN, открываем ветку реестра: 
>   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
>   Находим параметр и меняем значение:
>   IpEnableRouter типа REG_DWORD значение 1

Однако совет не помог. Вопрос: как же все-так добраться до второго компа?

[image]

Comment: Они же в разных подсетях. Маршруты для 4.1 пропишите в 3.x сеть route -p add ...

Comment: @sergarcada, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У вас машины однозначно должны друг друга пинговать по ip адресам vpn туннеля, это показывает, что туннель есть. Чтобы увидеть машины по ip адресам внутренних сетей, должна происходить внутренняя маршрутизация через vpn интерфейс. А чтобы виделись сети, должен быть известен у целевой пингуемой машины маршрут в отвечаемую сеть. Может так происходить, что пинг доходит в другую сеть до машины, но она не может доставить ответь по исходному ip адресу на ту машину, с которой был послан пакет, а если быть точным, она отправляет пакет на шлюз по умолчанию, если не указанно иное для целевой сети.

Таким образом, вам нужно прописать маршрут между сетями через туннель либо на шлюзах по умолчанию обоих сетей, либо на всех хостах статическим маршрутом.